# After AAS Model Pause and Resume, Attempting to Open an ADOMD.net Connection Returns 307 Response

Tags: c#, azure, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net

### Background

I have an API that makes uses the ADOMD.Net client to retrieve data from Azure Analysis Services (AAS) Model. A connection is created using a connection string that contains an access token obtained as documented [here](https://github.com/sanjaybhagia/azure-analysis-services-netcore-sample).

### Problem

The API works fine, until the AAS Model is paused and resumes which happens every night. After this, the Model returns a 207 Temporary Redirect response.

```
The remote server returned an error: (307) Temporary Redirect.

Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 4d85e2d9-e1ec-406d-92aa-3f3e33ac4ed4
Date (UTC): 3/9/2020 1:09:05 PM
```

The location in the header is:

```
https://asazureweu10-westeurope.asazure.windows.net/webapi/xmla
```

The original request (but made by the ADOMD.Net client, not me) is made to:

```
https://asazureweu5-westeurope.asazure.windows.net/webapi/xmla
```

After I restart the API the client starts responding with the data and functions correctly. This leads me to believe something is being cached, and once the API is restarted the cache is cleared maybe? Is this a Connection pooling issue?

Does anyone know what is happening behind the scenes and know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, wondering if you ever found a resolution to this. Have been running into the same issue.

Comment: Hi @CharlesBoyung so it's a bug. I've raised a support ticket in Azure and they have said they will fix this issue and release the fix in the next Nuget package update around Sept 2020.

Comment: Thanks @DanCundy, that's exactly what I needed to know. Client can wait for that (hoping September doesn't turn into next year)

Comment: @CharlesBoyung the patched version is has now been released and I've tested it and confirm they have fixed it.. See below for the appropriate catch block to catch and retry needed.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a verified bug which has been reported to MS.

The MS support engineer has said.

> The client library indeed caches this the cluster information in the
> AppDomain level cache, which has a timeout of 60 minutes. But there is
> an invalidation code that invalidates the cache on error code >= 300
> and <= 399. In this case, the error is 307 so the invalidation logic
> should still work, as long as the connection is closes and then opened
> again.

This bug is due to be patched in a late august, early September Nuget release.

**Update: This bug has now been patched in Nuget package microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64, version 19.9.0.1-Preview.**

The code snippet I'm using is as below.

```
        // Catch any error redirection errors and retry. Due to internal workings of lib, if model is scaled up or down, or paused and restarted,
        // the model will come back on a different cluster, so we need to get a new connection.
        catch (AdomdConnectionException ex)
        {
            if ((int) ((HttpWebResponse) ((WebException) ex.InnerException).Response).StatusCode >= 300
                & (int) ((HttpWebResponse) ((WebException) ex.InnerException).Response).StatusCode <= 399)
            {
                aasConnection = await GetOpenAasConnectionAsync(customData, role);
            }
            else throw;
        }
```